# change of integrand in integral representation of euler constant

Tags: analysis

In Julian Havil's book "Gamma" he gives an integral representation of gamma as:
$$-\gamma = \int_0^\infty \!\! e^{-u}\ln u\,\mathrm du = \int_0^1 e^{-u}\ln u\,\mathrm du + \int_1^\infty \!\! e^{-u}\ln u\,\mathrm du\\$$

He then transforms the first integral so that the equation reads
$$-\gamma =  -\int_0^1 \!\! (-e^{-u}+1)\ln u\,\mathrm du + \int_1^\infty \!\! e^{-u}\ln u\,\mathrm du$$

and keeps the second integrand the same. I am stumped on how he makes that change of integrands, and would appreciate any help.

Comment: This is wrong as written.  It would say $\int_0^1 \ln(u)\; du = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

As Robert Israel points out, the equation given would imply that $\int_0^1 \log(u)\,\mathrm{d}u=0$.

A common method for evaluating that integral (without referencing the Gamma function) is
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\log(t)\,e^{-t}\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^n\log(t)\,\left(1-\tfrac tn\right)^n\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{1}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_0^1\log(nt)\,(1-t)^n\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{2}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{n}{n+1}\log(n)+n\int_0^1\log(1-t)\,t^n\,\mathrm{d}t\right]\tag{3}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{n}{n+1}\log(n)-\frac{n}{n+1}\int_0^1\frac{1-t^{n+1}}{1-t}\,\mathrm{d}t\right]\tag{4}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}\left[\log(n)-\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1k\right]\tag{5}\\[6pt]
&=-\gamma\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\tfrac tn\right)^n[t\le n]=e^{-t}$ monotonically; apply Lebesgue Monotone Convergence
$(2)$: substitute $t\mapsto nt$
$(3)$: $\log(nt)=\log(n)+\log(t)$ then substitute $t\mapsto1-t$
$(4)$: integrate by parts
$(5)$: divide the polynomials and integrate
$(6)$: $\gamma=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac1k-\log(n)\right)$

Comment: Very nice! I'd feared that the evaluation might be more byzantine, involving one or more rabbits-out-of-hats. May I ask, where did you see this? Is it in Whittaker-and-Watson? Seems too clean to be anything they'd write out in detail, somehow.

Comment: Very good explanation, but I am still trying to understand where the(1-e^-t) in the integrand for gamma comes from.

Comment: @brayton: as mentioned in a comment by Robert Israel, that seems to be erroneous.

Comment: @paulgarrett: using series both for $\log(x)$ and for $e^{-t}$ fail. The next things to try are $\log(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n(x^{1/n}-1)$ and $e^{-x}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac xn\right)^n$. The latter works. Just a matter of trying representations.

Comment: A good dialectic explanation, too! Thx!

Comment: great explanation! many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this appears on page 107 of the paperback version of Gamma.  I think that you may have misread what it says, unless there is a typo in a version I do not have.  The first integral you give is not such, but a square bracket of evaluation after integration by parts has been carried out.

Best wishes,

Julian Havil

Comment: Thank you, I believe I have resolved my misunderstanding, I appreciate you getting back to me. I am truly enjoying your book.

Comment: Great news.  All good wishes with the rest of the book and I am delighted that you are enjoying it.

Comment: \documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\title{integral representation of Euler's constant}
\author{brayton bailey}
\date{July 2017}

\begin{document}
When I integrate by parts on the first of the two integrals I get:
$$\int_0^1\!\! (e^{-u}  lnu du = [-e^{-u} lnu]_0^1 + \int_0^1 \!\!\frac{ e^{-u}}{u} du $$
I still don't see where the :
$$ [(-e^{-u} +1)lnu]_0^1 - \int_0^1 \!\! \frac{(-e^{-u}+1)}{u} du $$  comes from.
It is that 1 that keeps messing me up. 
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}

Comment: whoops, sorry the latex text didn't come through properly, disregard

Comment: I am still stumped on where the 1 comes from, as I only come up with e^-u lnu evaluated from 0 to 1 plus the integral of e^-u/u ln u du when I integrate by pars.